# CSS Toggle Switch without classes / id

Tags: html, css, checkbox, toggle

I am working right now on a project for my web-engineering course at my university. We have to create some kind of school management site and are , right now , only allowed to use plain HTML and CSS with the restriction that we work in CSS without classes and ids , only selectors are allowed.

Now i wanted to add a toggle switch button to our page and i found this website (https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/) where you can create your own toggle button. But the code you receive works with classes which I am not allowed to use so i tried to alter the code so that it would just use selectors but it won´t work.
Maybe someone can help me here to understand my mistake ( beside copying a code snippet instead of working out something ).

```css
div:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  width: 67px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background-color: #FA1212;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
}
label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 43px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 22px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #28CF25;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked +label:before {
  border-color: #28CF25;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" checked>
  <label for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use classes, as long as the label has a `for="..."` which is the same as the input's `id="..."`, and quite rightly the label appears **after** the input tag.

The `for` attribute on the label element links to the `id` attribute on the input element and the browser does the rest.

A quick demo below demonstrates this:

```css
html{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);text-align:center;font-size:2em;}
input:checked + label {
  background: lime;
}
input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
input + label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px black, 2px 2px 5px black;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input + label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  left: calc(100% - 35px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}
input:checked + label:before {
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
Click My toggle Checkbox
<br/><br/>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" />
  <label for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , with including the id into the input tag it does work now. Is it better to use attribute selectors e.g. input[type="checkbox"]:checked instead of just input:checked or does it not make a difference since only checkboxes can be "checked" ?

Comment: If you're using radio buttons, then the attribute would be beneficial. Otherwise, `:checked` would be sufficient